# Resources$NotFoundException -- Weather app

Tags: android

`Error while installing the app.`

> Error--"android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>
> ## 0xffffffff"

Please help..

```
int viewType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());
        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_TODAY: {
                // Get weather icon
                viewHolder.iconView.setImageResource(Utility.getArtResourceForWeatherCondition(
                        cursor.getInt(ForecastFragment.COL_WEATHER_CONDITION_ID)));
                break;
            }
            case VIEW_TYPE_FUTURE_DAY: {
                // Get weather icon
                viewHolder.iconView.setImageResource(Utility.getIconResourceForWeatherCondition    (
                        cursor.getInt(ForecastFragment.COL_WEATHER_CONDITION_ID)));
                break;
            }
}
```

Comment: please add code and logcat

Comment: Logcat -- [gist](https://gist.github.com/kum4r-4nkit/4c22fed9f6783de4a13499b257a88b76) @Urvishrana

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are trying to give -1 in getString() function or while accessing some resource

**EDIT**:
After reviewing your github code, I got the reason of crash that

```
Utility.getIconResourceForWeatherCondition(cursor.getInt(ForecastFragment.COL_WEATHER_CONDITION_ID))
```

this Utility method, returns -1 in a case where

```
cursor.getInt(ForecastFragment.COL_WEATHER_CONDITION_ID)
```

this returns, `904` and 904 is not listed in any if-else conditions of Utility function, hence the last `return` statement returns `-1`. I guess, either there is an unintended entry in database or some conditions are missing in Utility function, or there is a third option that you return some default drawable instead of `-1` from the last return statement.

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I am unable to understand what you said, please can you explain where?

Comment: Post your activity/fragment code you where the error has occurred

Comment: What does `getArtResourceForWeatherCondition()` function return? Or show it's code.

Comment: I guess that function returns an integer rather than id(which is also an integer), which is causing the error

Comment: here is the project through github?? [Github](https://github.com/kum4r-4nkit/Weather-Forecast)

Comment: You have not added drawables in github